# Accessing likelihood evaluations in pymc sampling

Tags: python, pymc, mcmc

I hope you can give me some useful hint on this one.

I want to perform function minimisation using MCMC.
My function L (which happens to be a -logGaussian) has 5 variables. In my code, I loop over the first (`J`) and holding it fixed, I sample L over the remaining 4 free variables (`a, b, c, r`).

The purpose of this is to build the "profile" of L along one specific direction in its multidimensional parameter space. Hence, I'm not interested in the posterior distribution of the 4 free parameters, but rather in the samples of the 4+1 parameters and the corresponding values of the function L, for each `J`.

Below the model I'm passing to a `pymc.MCMC` instance (schematically - not a MWE):

```
def model(J):
    a = Uniform('a', lower=0, upper=5)
    b = Uniform('b', lower=0, upper=5)
    c = Uniform('c', lower=0, upper=5)
    r = Uniform('r', lower=0, upper=5)

    @deterministic
    def loglike(J=J, a=a, b=b, c=c, r=r):
        return LL(a, b, J, r, c)

    return locals()
```

At this point, to obtain the tuple of values `(J, L, a, b, c, r)`, for J in a given range, I do the following:

```
for J in J_array:
    M = MCMC(model(J))
    M.sample(110000, burn=10000, thin=1000)

    L_sample = M.trace('loglike')[:]
    true_indx = ~np.isnan(L_sample)
    L_sample = L_sample[true_indx]
    min_indx = np.where( L_sample==L_sample.min() )[0][0]
    L = L_sample[min_indx]

    for par in ['a', 'b', 'c', 'r']:
        exec( "{p}_sample = M.trace('{p}')[:]".format(p=par) )
        exec( "{p}_sample = {p}_sample[true_indx]".format(p=par) )
        exec( "{p} = {p}_sample[min_indx]".format(p=par) )
```

My question is: am I doing it correctly?
Said otherwise: given my model, by using the `trace` method, am I accessing the values of the `loglike` function or its posterior values? In the latter case, how can I access the simple likelihood evaluations of the MCMC sampler?

Thank you very much for your help. Best, Andrea